# Need to VPN from LAMP webserver using .pcf. Is Cisco's linux client the only way?

Tags: linux, vpn, cisco-vpn

First off, I'm a VPN noob.  We have a web server (via MediaTemple) that is running Plesk.  Our client gave us .pcf files to connect to their VPN, which work locally with my mac Cisco VPN client.  Plesk has a VPN module and OpenVPN is installed on our webserver.  To anyone's knowledge, can I use either of these in conjunction with the .pcf file they sent us?  Or do I need to install the Linux version of Cisco's software on the webserver?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vpnc works well for this.  I have used [this script](http://svn.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/vpnc/branches/vpnc-0.4.0-hybrid/pcf2vpnc) in the past to convert pcf files to a configuration that works for vpnc.

I wrote a [blog post](http://www.kbrandt.com/2007/07/how-to-connect-to-cisco-vpn-with-ubuntu.html) on how to do this if you want some hand holding with the script, this is a bit old though ...

Comment: Yeah, VPNC ended up being the way to go.  It took a little fussing with but at long last it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 10+ has a Cisco-compatible VPN client included.  It appears to be 'vpnc', which is available here:  http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~massar/vpnc/

On Fedora 10+, NetworkManager has a GUI frontend for vpnc, but I'm sure the documentation can show you how to configure it without a GUI (if necessary).

I've used vpnc on Fedora 10 and 11 with no issues.  It's easy to deal with and I've never had problems connecting.